# How to select all marked 'seamed edges'

Tags: modeling, vertices

I have a maze and I want to select all of the 'seamed edges'.Maybe there is an addon for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with "Select Similar".
Select one of your edges with a seam, then go `Select > Select Similar > Seam`, to quickly select all the edges with seams.

[image: Seam]